# Simple game loop for a Haskell console game in Windows

Tags: haskell

I'd like to make snake in a console and write it in Haskell.

How should I go about refreshing the display (either by clearing it or just pushing in new stuff) periodically? I don't need a fixed framerate or anything fancy. Just a simple loop that executes some code every x milliseconds.

Secondly, how can I properly get input from the console without blocking it and without it requiring me to press enter.

I've read a couple of solutions to this but they all don't seem to work properly on windows. The one that does is Haskeline which I've tried to use with this code

```
main = 
    runInputT defaultSettings loop
    where
        loop :: InputT IO ()
        loop = do
            gotInput <- hReady stdin
            if gotInput
            then do
                input <- getInputChar ""
                case input of
                    Just chr -> outputStrLn [chr]
                    Nothing -> return ()
            else return ()
```

The issue here is that hReady stdin returns an IO monad when I need the one compatible with Haskeline. Excuse the terminology, I'm very new to monads and pretty new to Haskell in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up liftIO (from Control.Monad.IO.Class). Then type: gotInput <- liftIO $ hReady stdin

Comment: Hey! That was surprisingly simple. It works. What about the periodic loop part?

Comment: Instead of returning (), call loop again. That will set up the loop.